# How to show a second legend for a third variable in a scatter plot using plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization, legend, r-plotly

I have the following code producing a scatter plot (using [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) in [r](/questions/tagged/r))and I would like to add the [legend](/questions/tagged/legend) representing the size of the markers `totalValue` (it is a continuous variable representing the value of specific buildings), how could I do that?

```
 f <- list(
   family = "Courier New, monospace",
   size = 18,
   color = "#7f7f7f"
  )
 x <- list(
   title = "Age of Buildings",
   titlefont = f,
   zeroline = FALSE,
   showline = FALSE,
   showticklabels = TRUE,
   showgrid = TRUE
  )
  y <- list(
    title = "Total Violations",
    titlefont = f,
    zeroline = FALSE,
    showline = FALSE,
    showticklabels = TRUE,
    showgrid = TRUE
   )
fig2 <- plot_ly(final, x=~agebuilding, y=~violationstotal, mode= "markers", color = 
                ~INdexrehabless6, size = ~totalvalue)
fig2 <- fig2 %>% layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y, legend=list(title=list(text='<b> 
                        Housing Conditions </b>'))) #chaging name legend
fig2
```

sample of dataset:

```
agebuilding  violationstotal  INdexrehabless6  totalvalue
32            5                0                 350000
120          15                1                  50000
100          25                1                 100000
32           31                0                 210000
33            9                0                 150000
50           20                0                 301000
15           28                0                 175000
70           18                1                 125000
```

Here is the plot I get

[image]

Comment: can you provide a sample data set?

Comment: I just added a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To best of my knowledge, plotting with two legends in [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) is not possible yet:

- [https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1668]
- [https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1262]

Even with [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) (highly customisable) and [ggplotly](/questions/tagged/ggplotly) (a wrapper around [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly)), ultimately leads to only one legend.

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr); library(magrittr);

final <- read.table(header = T, text = 
                        "agebuilding  violationstotal  INdexrehabless6  totalvalue
32            5                0                 350000
120          15                1                  50000
100          25                1                 100000
32           31                0                 210000
33            9                0                 150000
50           20                0                 301000
15           28                0                 175000
70           18                1                 125000"); 

final;
  agebuilding violationstotal INdexrehabless6 totalvalue
1          32               5               0     350000
2         120              15               1      50000
3         100              25               1     100000
4          32              31               0     210000
5          33               9               0     150000
6          50              20               0     301000
7          15              28               0     175000
8          70              18               1     125000

#plots the ggplot in `plot` window. 1st GRAPH
ggplot(data = final, aes(x = agebuilding, y = violationstotal)) + 
    geom_point(aes(size = totalvalue, color = INdexrehabless6))

# plots the ggploty in viewer window. 2nd GRAPH (interactive)
ggp %>% ggplotly();
```

**1st GRAPH**
[image]

**2nd GRAPH**
[image]

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer @massisenergy. Hope plotly can come up with a way to do it. I can achieve it by using ggplot2 and then to make it interactive in plotly. Although it will be better to have the option enabled in plotly itself so I can have more control in the details with plotly